# Measuring the time it takes to manually insert data in MongoDB using mongosh - any tips?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, mongodb-compass

Measuring the time of inserting data into mongoDB

I'm using mongoDB Compass, but I'd like to enter the data manually through the built-in mongosh and measure its time. There is something like explain("executionStats"), but for the insertMany() command? I will also need to measure time of update and delete.

Comment: It doesn't exit.Just insert the data and stop the time